# Using NCrawler to crawl password protected sites

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I have a C# Crawler app based on NCrawler, to which I want to add cookie support. Something very basic, a predefined user and password that will match a specific site. However I can't seem to find where to define the credentials.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using webclient?

Comment: And have you tried the `UseCookies` property?

Comment: Not using webclient. UseCookies is just a flag; how do I state my credentials? thanks

Comment: Based on experience with webclient only, you usually need to submit the credentials to the login page, traditionally that page has html fields such as **user** and **pwd** and then it will hand you back the cookie(s).  I would guess that setting `UseCookies` to true when making that initial call, and then using the same crawler object to call the desired secured page should do the trick.